# "Working-level talks" meaning in a news about negotiations

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of *working level talks*?

It is in [a headline](https://thediplomat.com/2019/10/north-korea-working-level-talks-with-us-to-resume-october-5/) about U.S and North Korea negotiations.

Comment: You should edit additional information/sources into the question as comments can be deleted.

Answer (score -1):

**high-level** talks / **working level** talks  [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/high-level)

adjective

> If discussions are high-level, very important people are involved in
>   them: high-level meetings/talks between the two sides.

In diplomacy, progress can be made in these difficult talks with important people, **but** the major decision makers such as the heads of state, top diplomats etc... do not attend.

Comment: _'Working-level' talks_ aren't mentioned either as a synonym or in contrast.